# Backbone Router not working with pushState

Tags: .htaccess, backbone.js, requirejs, router, pushstate

I want to have every page request redirect to my `index.html`, and any link **(not #urls - /real/urls)** clicked in my app to run through `router.js` so there are essentially no page refreshes - purely ajax. Is there an easy way to do this with Backbone routing and htaccess?

I have it working at the moment if I take away `{pushState: true}` and format my links like `#login`. However, when I enable `pushState` and click on `#login`, nothing happens. Instead, it is only once I refresh the page that Backbone interprets the `#login` and follows the route to render `loginView`.

Here is my router:

```
// Filename: router.js
define( [ 'views/beta/requestInvite', 'views/beta/login' ],
function(requestInviteView, loginView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend( {
        routes : {
            // Pages
            'login' : 'login',

            // Default
            '*actions' : 'defaultAction'
        },

        // Pages
        login : function() {
            loginView.render();
        },

        defaultAction : function(actions) {
            requestInviteView.render();
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    };
    return {
        initialize : initialize
    };
});
```

What I would like to happen is in `requestInviteView`, when the link to `/login` is clicked, the url changes to `/login` and the `loginView` is rendered.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing from hash to pushstate is not that trivial as changing single parameter as one may be led to think. What i do is catch the click event in my view and call app.navigate to trigger the route.

```
app.navigate("/login", {trigger: true});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate

Comment: You can do this somewhat automatically using a method similar to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/colllin/5717284).

Answer (score 5):

Although Anthony's answer will work, using `trigger: true` is usually not the best course of action. Instead your app should be structured so you can call `navigate` with the default `trigger` value left to `false`.

Derick Bailey talks about the issue on his blog at http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/ (paragraph "The “AHA!” Moment Regarding Router.Navigate’s Second Argument")

In addition, an entire chapter explaining routing in more detail (including why you should leave `trigger` to `false`) can be dowloaded for free in this pdf book sample: http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf (full disclosure: I'm the book author)

Comment: interesting, but replicating the logic for every controller just to avoid a second parameter seems redundant. i have rare scenarios in which i use this (ie. when a route is requested out of order i change it on the fly and render the proper view). the context of this question is to trigger an action after a link is clicked, and imo i see triggering it as the best of doing this.